# how to get the last letters of the char input in java

Tags: input, char, bluej

Suppose user entered 'my name is xyz' so how would i get the last three letters 'xyz' in BlueJ. What code should i use to get last or the first letters of the input. In Q basic it is easy by using Right$ and Lest$ but I don't know how to do it in BlueJ.

Comment: Java does not have right() or left() functions, but instead of that, you can use Reverse(), Substring(), indexOf(), and etc. google it yourself

Answer (score 0):

String input = "my name is xyz";

String lastThree = "" + input.charAt(input.length-3) + input.charAt(input.length-2) + input.charAt(input.length-1);

Answer (score 0):

In case of strings you should make use of the stringtokenizer class as it converts all the words of a sentence into tokens and makes it easier to access each word in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

`Substring` is a good way of getting certain characters from a string. You could use something like:

```
String lastThree = input.substring(input.charAt(input.length() - 3), input.length());
```